# Just started using Android Studio And wanted to make an app using CameraX

Tags: android-camerax, android-developer-api

When I copy the code given by the android website it shows errors even though I have followed the instructions perfectly. Code was written in Kotlin.

One example would be:

```
def camerax_version = "1.3.0-rc01""
```

Which after some research was supposed to be:

```
val camerax_version = "1.3.0-rc01"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin uses the val keyword to declare variables, not def.

In Kotlin, the val keyword is used to declare immutable variables, while the var keyword is used to declare mutable variables. In the example you provided, the variable camerax_version is being declared as immutable, so you should use the val keyword.